# Important files possibly leaked into mapped network drive

Tags: windows, networking, hard-drive

I recently mapped a network drive. While moving important sensitive files. I accidentally dragged one into it. The computer froze for a while and went back to normal, there was no indication of file transferring or anything, just freezing for a awhile. I panicked and I tried to open the drive but the drive seemed to be offline, it says not responding.

Normally when I used that drive in my workplace, the drive will ask for authentication before letting me  in.

Is there a possibility that my file was leaked into the network drive? I am using Windows 8.1

This happened when I was at home.

Comment: Can you simply just verify the file doesn't exist on the shared drive.

Comment: When I tried to open the drive after I made the mistake, it could not open. It showed me a diagnose option which I have clicked on too and said that "My computer seem to be configured but the server is not responding".

Comment: The drive will ask for authentication every time I go in normally. When I made the mistake, the computer froze for awhile but did not ask for anything. Is it possible for anything to get leaked into the drive?

Answer (score 0):

The only way it could be copied to the mapped drive would be if the drive were connected at the time. Otherwise, the transfer request would time out (probably why it seemed to freeze) and cancelled. You should have gotten an error message stating the drive was unavailable.

To be sure, when you reconnect to your network at work, go to that drive and see if the file is there. I highly doubt you will find it.

Comment: When I tried to open the drive after I made the mistake, it could not open. It showed me a diagnose option which I have clicked on too and said that "My computer seem to be configured but the server is not responding".

Comment: The drive will ask for authentication every time I go in normally. When I made the mistake, the computer froze for awhile but did not ask for anything. Is it possible for anything to get leaked into the drive? What happened was that the file icon hovered over the drive on the left sidebar of explorer, when I tried to click on anything, it would say not responding, if I wait for a while, it would return back to normal. I certainly MUST not have the file leaked into the drive, there are permissions that only allow me to write and read but not overwrite or delete.

Comment: I understand what you are asking. If you are not connected to the network where the mapped drive exists, you won't be able to "*open*" the drive. That means you will not be prompted for authentication. SO...if you are not connected to the drive, I'm 99.9% confident nothing was "*leaked*" onto the drive.

Comment: Thank you. I just found out that the is only acessible when I have a VPN to the workplace. So I guess stuff cannot be transferred outside.

Comment: Using a VPN from home is an important detail to know when trying answer a question like this. In the future, please include those types of things.